# can't install cpan module under cygwin

Tags: cygwin, cpan

I'm trying to install perl's module Date:Parse on cygwin, but no luck:

```
cpan Date::Parse
```

Any ideas?  It seems that other modules are having trouble installing as well.

Output:

```
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
Going to read '/home/xxxxxxxx/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Wed, 18 Jan 2012 19:10:27 GMT
Running install for module 'Date::Parse'
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v0.71)
Running make for G/GB/GBARR/TimeDate-1.20.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.47)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.02)
Checksum for /home/xxxxxxxx/.cpan/sources/authors/id/G/GB/GBARR/TimeDate-1.20.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v1.52)
TimeDate-1.20/
TimeDate-1.20/ChangeLog
(...)
TimeDate-1.20/lib/Date/Language/Turkish.pm
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)

  CPAN.pm: Going to build G/GB/GBARR/TimeDate-1.20.tar.gz

Not a CODE reference at /home/xxxxxxxx/lib/perl/File/Find.pm line 126.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
  GBARR/TimeDate-1.20.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
```

The `perl -version` output is: "This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for i686-cygwin-thread-multi-64int (with 13 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)".

Answer (score 1):

From http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2010-02/msg00242.html :

Looks like you're missing 'make'.  I would start by checking to see if you've installed the package.